# Android Parse XML based on date value

Tags: java, android, xml

How would I only return/parse the node elements that have a specific value.

Below is my simple XML but I only need the `time`, `meeting_name` and `host_name` from the `meeting_item`'s that have a date of `2012-03-09`:

```
<meeting_item>
    <time>12:30</time>
    <date>2012-03-09</date>
    <meeting_name>build a shop 4</meeting_name>
    <host_name>Bob Jones</host_name>
</meeting_item>
<meeting_item>
    <time>11:30</time>
    <date>2012-03-23</date>
    <meeting_name>build a shop advance</meeting_name>
    <host_name>Judy Washington</host_name>
</meeting_item>
<meeting_item>
    <time>11:30</time>
    <date>2012-03-23</date>
    <meeting_name>build a shop 2</meeting_name>
    <host_name>Tom Smith</host_name>
</meeting_item>
<meeting_item>
    <time>11:30</time>
    <date>2012-04-06</date>
    <meeting_name>build a shop 3</meeting_name>
    <host_name>Tom Green</host_name>
</meeting_item>
```

**Below is my parsing code so far but this just gets everything in the file:**

```
        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(items);
        Log.d(TAG, xml);
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
 int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

        if((numResults <= 0)){
            Toast.makeText(MeetingManager.this, "NOT GETTING XML", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            finish();
        }

        Element docElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nl = docElem.getElementsByTagName("Meeting_Data");
        Element elem = (Element)nl.item(1);
        NodeList nodes = elem.getElementsByTagName("meeting_item");



        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("time", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "time"));
            map.put("name", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "meeting_name"));
            map.put("hostname", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "host_name"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MeetingManager.this, mylist , R.layout.listlayout, 
                        new String[] {"time", "name", "hostname" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.time, R.id.meeting_name, R.id.host });

       setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Also in my logCat  Log.d(TAG, xml);  doesn't make it all the way through the file. And sometimes throws and error about not reading all of the file. Is there a limit I can httpGet?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to parse a portion of the xml file I recomend you use something like the XmlPullParser or the SaxParser. As the dom parser will try to create a complete tree of objects based on your xml data. To do this with xml pull parser, your parsing code would look like

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
factory.setValidating(false);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(is,"UTF-8");

int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
outerloop: 
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    switch(eventType){
        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT: 
            Log.e("Start","Start");
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            Log.e("StartTag", xpp.getName());
            break;                      
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            Log.e("EndTag", xpp.getName());
                  //When you need to stop parsing use this
                  break outerloop;
            break;
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```